# How would I place an attribute outside of fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I have 2 models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :prices_attributes, :business_name
  has_many :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :product_name, :purchase_date
  belongs_to :store
end
```

I'm creating a Store and Prices together making it a nested form:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @store = Store.new
    3.times {@store.prices.build }
  end
end
```

Nested form:

```
<%= form_for @store do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :business_name %>

  <%= date_select("price", "purchase_date")  %>

  <%= f.fields_for :prices do |up| %>
    <%= up.text_field :product_name %>
    <%= up.text_field :price %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to place the `purchase_date` outside of my `f.fields_for` so users only have to choose one `date_select` for all prices made. This doesn't work though. The `purchase_date` does not show up on the form. How can I get it do this?

Comment: I have to admit, I'm a bit confused by what you are going for here.  Are the 'purchase_date' and 'purchased' attributes of a business_store or a user_price, or both?

Comment: The `purchase date` and `purchased` belong to the user price. Let me update it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ...and what are the contents of the user_prices/fields partial?

Comment: @miked I updated my form, but the fields are `:product_name` and `:price`.

Comment: I posted an answer below with general info. When the user sets the purchased flag will you be updating the children's inputs or do you plan to handle setting the children's attributes only on the server side?

Comment: @miked they will be on the server side. Using something along these lines: `@user_prices = current_user.user_prices.create(params[:user_prices].map { |_k, up| up.merge params[:user_price] })` I just have to figure out how to do that with the nested form because this code is for creating `user_prices` alone. The first thing to figure out though is how to get these `user_price` fields to show up (purchase date and purchased).

Comment: @miked Sorry I just ready what you meant by server and client side in this case and yes, It is actually server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child forms display the purchased_date and purchased inputs - and you want to set the values of those inputs based on the input values in the parent form - you're going to have to script that on the client side (javascript/jquery) so the children's values get set in response to the parent input's change event (or similar).

If the child forms do not show these inputs, you will have to set the children's attributes on the server side (model or controller) based on the parent's attributes (if you choose to add them to the parent) or by using the params sent on the request.